# inclusion between two line bundles associated to divisors

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I just started to study line bundles and I'm stuck in the following:

Let $C$ be a projective curve, $U\subseteq C$ an open, $S:=C\setminus U$.

We have $\mathcal{O}(-(n+1)S)\subseteq \mathcal{O}(-nS)$.

Why does this inclusion hold?

I thought, we had:

$\mathcal{O}(-(n+1)S)=\mathcal{O}(-nS)\otimes \mathcal{O}(S)^{-1}$ (due to Prop. 6.13 b), chapter II, Hartshorne),

then I would conclude

$\mathcal{O}(-nS)\subseteq \mathcal{O}(-nS)\otimes \mathcal{O}(S)^{-1}=\mathcal{O}(-(n+1)S)$.

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Locally, elements of O(-(n+1)S) look like functions with zeros of order at least (n+1) at each point of S. They sit naturally inside the set of functions with zeros of order at least n.

Comment: Although John Brevik has explained completely, if you want to understand things the way you describe in the question, note that you have things the wrong way round: $O(S)^{-1}$ is an _ideal sheaf_, so $O(S)^{-1} \subset O_C$: tensoring by $O(-nS)$ then gives the result.